# How to avoid public emails in a site registration?

Tags: email, email-spam, email-client

i want to avoid public email / free emails like (@gmail.com,@yahoo.com.,) in site registration ..

Comment: Good for you! Now what's your question?

Comment: As opposed to what kind of email address?

Comment: @Bears will eat you: *How to avoid public emails in a site registration?*

Comment: Why would you want to do this anyway it's a pain in the ass and there are millions of potential legitimate users out there that have nothing but a gmail/hotmail/yahoo account.

Comment: Why don't you remove the ability to register for your site, since it's effectively useless if you are banning all free/public emails.

Comment: I don't know about your users, but I refuse to use anything other than my gmail account for site registrations (the other options being college email and work email).  Also, I'm sure non-public e-mail domains are two steps ahead of you from when they said "i want to avoid our e-mail users from getting spam e-mails from sites they used our company e-mail to register on" about 10 years ago. That pretty much leaves you with verizon and prolog e-mail users...ok maybe I exaggerate but you get the idea...

Comment: Please enter your username and password below....

Comment: @Felix - it's too early for me to figure out whether or not you're serious. Sad face :(

Comment: Could you provide the reason why you would want to do this.  Otherwise people are just going to leave a lot of comments saying this is a stupid idea.

Comment: @Bears will eat you: Actually I am serious. Yes the question would need way lot more information and the usefulness is also questionable but imo a proper question is stated in the title. Anyway, no hard feelings and good morning ;)

Answer (score 4):

So just parse the email address and compare the domain to your blacklist...

Comment: I would use a whitelist though... The number of public email domains out there is pretty large...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot determine what the user is paying based on the email address. All you can hope for this way is to blacklist a few of the more popular domains - but then, there is an infinity of others left. I know hardly anyone paying money for (just) their email address, so the question IMHO is rather what kind of user you want to avoid.

An even better question might be what kind of user you want to encourage.

Answer (score -1):

Put some JavaScript on your form similar to this:

script type="text/javascript" src="/js/public/jquery-latest.min.js" language="JavaScript">

    // set no conflict mode for jquery
  var $jQ = jQuery.noConflict();

```
//edit this list with the domains you want to block
```

var invalidDomains = ["@gmail.com","@yahoo.com","@hotmail.com"];

function formSubmit(elt) {
    if (!isEmailGood()) {
       form.setError($jQ("#Email")[0],"The address must be from a business address, not a free service");
       return false;
    }
    return form.formSubmit(elt);
  }

function isEmailGood() {
    for(i=0; i < invalidDomains.length; i++) {
      if ( $jQ("#Email[value*=" + invalidDomains[i] + "]").length > 0) {
          return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
/script>

Comment: Client side javascript should not be used for validation.  Validation should always be performed on the server -- if the client validates data, it should do it as well as the server, not instead.